# Nx no longer supports the v2 format of angular.json

Tags: javascript, angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I am trying to upgrade angular (v15) and nx (v16) in my project, but the issue that I am running into is when I start my project NX throws an error:

```
 >  NX   angular.json format is incorrect

   Nx no longer supports the v2 format of angular.json.
   Run "nx g @nx/workspace:fix-configuration" to split angular.json into individual project.json files. (Recommended)
   If you want to preserve angular.json, run "nx g @nx/workspace:fix-configuration --reformat"
```

Which is confusing to me, as my project is already split into `project.json` files. I did try to run the two suggested commands, it succeeds, but no files get updated...

Here is my `angular.json` file which looks like it is the correct format:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/nx/schemas/workspace-schema.json",
  "version": 2,
  "projects": {
    "xxx": "libs/xxx",
    "xxx-e2e": "apps/xxx-e2e",
    "yyy": "libs/yyy",
    "yyy-e2e": "apps/yyy-e2e"
  }
}
```

Then, I have the `project.json` where each one looks like this (where `xxx` is the project and some contain `-e2e` and others don't depending on if the project is an e2e application or a library):

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "name": "xxx-e2e",
  // Either the e2e schema
  // or the library schema
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What solved the issue for me, was just removing the `angular.json`, as NX no longer uses the `angular.json` file. The data is stored in the `project.json`, and NX seems to load all of the `project.json` files (probably using a glob).

So, my solution: Delete (or rename) the `angular.json`.

Comment: THANK YOU... I have spent the day trying to update my NX workspace -- the only error I was getting was: Failed to run 15-7-0-split-configuration-into-project-JSON-files from @nrwl/workspace.  For others having this problem - it does have to do with the angular.json file.   Removed it and am able to run migrations.